# request.getresponse() giving error bad username and password

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to access a file using `request.getstream()` on a server A. I have also given the network credentials. Those credentials have admin rights on that server.

But while using `request.getresponse()` the following error is shown:

> Login failure: bad username and password.

Can anybody suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: Probably bad username or password. Remember the server is right, and you're wrong. You need to find out _how_ you could be wrong. Look at the network traffic and find out what you did wrong (like not authenticate).

Comment: Are you trying to access to a database or a file?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to supply the domain as well in the username for instance "DOMAIN\USERNAME"